# What might the problem in this PHP code to find Sum in mysql column stored using adodb?

Tags: php, mysqli, adodb

I am trying to find a sum of a column in mysql table but I get an error as below.

```
    <?php   require_once("../../../../512/1.001/data/class.php"); 
$sql=mysqli_query($db,"select SUM(tbl_ccp_loans.payableamount) AS total");  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql); 
$sum = $row['total'];
$sum;?>
```

I expect the Total sum is 'Number' but the output is

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /home/testing/public_html/orrf/bej/ccp-main2/_dashboard/data.php on line 223
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/testing/public_html/orrf/bej/ccp-main2/modules/_dashboard/data.php on line 224

Comment: How do you set `$db`?

Comment: @Zhorov
{`code` 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors',true);

@require_once('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
@require_once('adodb/adodb-active-record.inc.php');

$db_type  = 'mysqli';
$db_host  = 'localhost';
$db_user  = 'testing';
$db_pass  = 'fridaymoods';
$db_name  = 'jacaranda';

$db = ADONewConnection($db_type);

if(! @$db->Connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name)){
  echo("Could Not Connect to {$db_host}/{$db_name} ");
}

$db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);

ADODB_Active_Record::SetDatabaseAdapter( $db );

$pubKey = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
`code`}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) expects as first parameter object of [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) class (returned by [mysqli_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)), but based on code in your comments, your `$db` variable is an object of different class. If this is a custom class, try to use appropriate methods from this class to execute a query and retrieve results.

Next is a basic example using `mysqli_connect()`.

```
<?php   
require_once("../../../../512/1.001/data/class.php"); 

$db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$db) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "select SUM(tbl_ccp_loans.payableamount) AS total"); 
if ($sql === false) {
    echo 'Error. ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql); 
$sum = $row['total'];
echo $sum;
?>
```